# Simplify $\sqrt[3]{162x^6y^7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The answer is $3x^2 y^2 \sqrt[3]{6y}$

How does $\sqrt[3]{162x^6y^7}$ equal $3x^2 y^2\sqrt[3]{6y}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{162x^6y^7}&=\sqrt[3]{27x^6y^6*6y}\\
&=\sqrt[3]{27x^6y^6}\times\sqrt[3]{6y}\\
&=3x^2y^2\sqrt[3]{6y}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$162x^6y^7=(3x^2y^2)^3\cdot6y$, such that

$$\sqrt[3]{162x^6y^7}=\sqrt[3]{(3x^2y^2)^3\cdot6y}=\sqrt[3]{(3x^2y^2)^3}\sqrt[3]{6y}=3x^2y^2\sqrt[3]{6y}$$

Answer (score 2):

First note that 162 factors as $2\cdot 3^4$. So collecting our powers of 3 reveals
$$\sqrt[3]{162x^6y^7}  = \sqrt[3]{3^3 \cdot (x^3)^2\cdot (y^3)^2 \cdot (2\cdot 3  \cdot y)}  = 3x^2y^2\sqrt[3]{6y}.$$